# Find the binary of decimal numbers given with powers of 10

Tags: binary, decimal-expansion, binary-operations

Convert to binary : 46.5 * 10^(-24)
Or something like 46.5 * 10^(24)

I have to find the binary equivalents here, for the purpose of representation in IEEE 754 floating point representation. But I cannot convert the powers of 10 to binary! Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we divide or multiply by 2 when converting binary?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262109/why-do-we-divide-or-multiply-by-2-when-converting-binary)

Comment: There are some related questions, for instance, one more general [about converting to binary](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262109/why-do-we-divide-or-multiply-by-2-when-converting-binary) and one specific to the [IEEE 754](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144659/an-algorithm-to-convert-float-number-to-binary-representation/2163204#2163204)

Comment: Yes, but they involve just small floating point numbers. Not huge ones or extremely small ones

Comment: I don't see the problem. Why don't you start by multiplying by $2^n$, where $n = \lceil -\log_2 x \rceil$ (so, rounded up).

Answer (score 1):

The method for converting a decimal number less than $1$ to binary uses repeated multiplication by $2$.
$$2(0.00465)=0.0093$$
$$2(0.0093)=0.0186$$
$$2(0.0186)=0.0372$$
$$2(0.0372)=0.0744$$
$$2(0.0744)=0.1488$$
$$2(0.1488)=0.2976$$
$$2(0.2976)=0.5952$$
$$2(0.5952)=1.1904$$
$$2(0.1904)=0.3808$$
$$2(0.3808)=0.7616$$
$$2(0.7616)=1.5232$$
$$2(0.5232)=1.0464$$
continuing this process of doubling the fractional part of the result gives the infinite binary expansion of the number in the units column. That is to say
$$(0.00465)_{10}\approx(0.000000010011)_2$$

Comment: What if the exponent is very small, like 10 to the power of -24? In that case we can't do this right..

Comment: You can - it just requires more multiplications to be made. I'm quite sure this is the easiest way to convert such a decimal number into binary as there is no quick way to convert $10^{-n}$ to binary. The binary expansion of $10^{-n}$ is infinitely long (although periodic). For example $(10^{-1})_{10}=(0.0\overline{0011})_2$